# Include own JDK in JAR

Tags: maven, javafx, java-8, executable-jar

I have a JavaFX-/Maven-Project which requires JDK 8 Update 40. I know that there are many computers without this version in my school class.

How can I deliver this version of JDK with my executable JAR?

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?q=bundling+jre+with+java+application

Comment: You can bundle the JRE with the native self-contained applications, but you can't do that in a `Jar`. Because Jar is platform independent where as JRE isn't.

Comment: Another option is to use Java Webstart for deployment and specify the version of Java that you require - that will ask the user to download the appropriate version if they don't have it already.

Answer (score 4):

As you are already using Maven and JavaFX, use the [Maven JavaFX plugin](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/) to [build a native installer](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/native-bundle.html) that bundles the Java runtime with your application.

```
mvn clean jfx:native
```

You can follow the [quick start guide](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/basic-archetype.html) to get a sample project up and running quickly.

Using the Maven JavaFX plugin tool will create a self-contained application as described in the [Oracle self-contained application documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html).  The Oracle documentation covers performing similar tasks for ant based builds or packaging using the `javapackager` command line tool.  It also covers the pre-requisite software you will need to install (e.g. wix or innosetup on Windows, or rpmbuild on Linux).  As well as other information such as how to customize the resultant bundle and set installer icons, etc.

In addition to the built-in formats such as rpm, exe, etc. which are directly supported by the Maven/JavaFX packaging tools, according to the Oracle guide:

> You can also assemble your own packages by post-processing a self-contained application packaged as a folder, for example if you want to distribute your application as a ZIP file.

I don't have a sample project which bundles an application with a JRE into a ZIP file.  It will probably be simpler for you to bundle and distribute as a native installer, as discussed earlier, rather than as a ZIP file.

Note that all of the packaging techniques discussed here address bundling the JRE with your application JAR, not in your application JAR.  Basically you have a higher level container format (e.g. ZIP, EXE, etc) which contains both the JRE and your application JAR and associated resources and the user activates the higher level container (e.g. unzips the ZIP OR installs the EXE) and that places the application JAR and a local JRE which is only used by your application on the users system.

Comment: The OP asks for bundling JRE in a jar, which isn't possible. May be you can add an explanation about it in your answer. I have already added [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509754/include-own-jdk-in-jar#comment47176909_29509754) on the question, but an explanation in an answer is always useful :)

Comment: I'm asking because I didn't know that. I just want to execute my program on every windows computer.

Answer (score 2):

While you can not include the JRE within your JAR. You can very well provide a single click installation using a third party tool like [Advanced Installer
Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/java.html) (pay), [InstallAnywere](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/producer/products/software-installation/installanywhere/) (pay), [JWrapper](http://www.jwrapper.com/) (free), [IzPack](http://izpack.org/) (free) or something similar. That way you can define which version of the JRE has to be present when installing your application.